# Choosing first location of the SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

This very well may not be possible.

I am performing a SOQL with a user's Id to get their name and I would like for this to be a one liner pretty much.

What I'm wondering if there is a way to do is the following

```
String userName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId LIMIT 1][0].Name;
```

I would like to access the SOQL array directly and get the occurence. Is something like this possible?

Comment: You want to do this in only one line, right ?

Comment: That's the goal

Comment: I can do it in two lines but not one :) !

Comment: You do mean first and last name as opposed to their username, correct?

Comment: Correct. Name will contain first and last name

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted is possible and does work. SO yes, one liner is possible.

This is a valid statement

```
String userName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId LIMIT 1][0].Name;
```

Comment: Ok, so you posted a question without try your code before ?!

Comment: Have you tried that? It should throw an error as the query won't return a list.

Comment: I didn't try it first cause I was being lazy (trait of my profession). But yes, I have tried it and it does work. Even though it is a limit to 1, I believe that it is returning an array with just one item in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String userName = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId LIMIT 1];`